# Asynctask, first call "onPostExecute" and after "doInBackground"

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I have got a problem with my code. I'm using an asynctask to download a JSON object from the web, and insert it into a list.

The part were I download the JSON is done "in the background", and then I put that object into an array in the `OnprogressUpdate()` method. Then a call to the `onPostExecute()` method is made to set the adapter.

But this doesnt seem to work  because `onPostExecute()` is called before `doInBackground()`.
Why?

Here is my code:

```
   public class getListData extends AsyncTask<Void, Song, Long>{

        @Override   
        protected Long doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            int state =0;
            AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

            client.get("http://192.168.1.9:8080/", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(JSONArray jsonArray) {
                    System.out.println("Successo");

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++)
                {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                try {
                    jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    System.out.println("Leggo il vettore di json");
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        Log.e("canta tu", ""+e);
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String Prezzo = null;

                try {

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                String Titolo = "";
                String ImgUrl="";
                String Genere = null;
                int Difficult = 0;
                String Autore = null;

                try {
                    Titolo =  jsonObject.getString("name"); // per la chiave name,l'informazine sul titolo
                    Autore = jsonObject.getString("artist"); //per l'autore
                    Genere = jsonObject.getString("genre"); //per il genere
                    Difficult = jsonObject.getInt("difficult"); //per la difficoltà
                    ImgUrl = jsonObject.getString("image_url"); //sarà image_url
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Song t = new Song(Titolo, Autore, Genere, Prezzo, Difficult, ImgUrl);
                System.out.println("inserisco " + Titolo); 
                publishProgress(t);
            }
        }   

        public void onFailure(Throwable e, JSONObject errorResponse){

            System.out.println("error : " + errorResponse);
        }
    });


     return (long) image_details.size(); //the size is 0 because it's called before the onProgressUpdate method

}

        @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Song... values)
            {
                for (Song song : values)
                {
                    image_details.add(song);
                }


            }

        protected void onPostExecute(Long bb) {
            System.out.println("download finished " +bb);
            lv1.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapterLele(getApplicationContext(), image_details));
         }

        }
```

Can any one point out whats wrong .

Thanks

Comment: onPostExecute is not called before doInbackground(). check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html check the topic under The 4 steps

Comment: I'm not sure what AsyncHttpClient is but judging by its name it fetches the JSON asynchronously. So the doInBackground method does not block and finishes with the Asynchronous request running in some other thread(probably). Use `DefaultHttpClient` or `HttpUrlConnection` and you should be good.

Comment: @Raghunandan i know that onPostExecute normally is after doInBackGround. The problem is that it run before.

Comment: @Akash thank's for your answers, maybe you are right, but if i don't call asyncHttpClient, and use defaultHttpClient i'm not able to download and work with the json.
Is possibile call 2 different onPostExecute? maybe changing the parameters...

Comment: @Lele you are wrong again. it has something to do with your code. onPostExecute is invoked after doInbackground computation finishes

Comment: isn't `override` compulsory for super class implementation?

Comment: @Lele there shouldnt be any reason why you cant download and work with the JSON using `DefaultHttpClient`

Comment: You have an asynctask within an asynctask.  `client.get("http://192.168.1.9:8080/", new JsonHttpResponseHandler()` This is an asyncCall, it does not waits and program goes immedialtely to onPostExecute() just after this line. WRONG IMPLEMENTATION of AsyncTask. Quick Solution can be just remove the AsyncTask and call this in UIThread and in onSuccess do the UI Updates using some handler.

Comment: @ChintanRathod nothing changes with Override

Comment: Thank's to all
I've solved. i create a new class that download the json, without call asyncronous metod, and put she in "doInBackground" now work. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onPostExecute() is not called before doInbackground() this  can't happen
Just use this JSON parser and only pass it the url of the page to get JSON from like

```
jsonobject = JSONParser
            .getJSONfromURL("http://10.0.2.2/myapi/products.php");
```

then parse the json object the way you like

```
public class JSONParser {

    public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url){
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONObject jObj = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try{
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                result=sb.toString();
        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }

        try{

            jObj = new JSONObject(result);            
        }catch(JSONException e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        }

        return jObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: And if i need to download a json array and not only a json object?

Comment: use the function getJSONArray

Answer (score 3):

I think calling

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); instead of AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
```

Should do the job.Hope it helps

Comment: i'm not able to work with json without the asyncHttpClient, because it have all the method.
I try with
 `HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    ((AsyncHttpClient) httpClient).get("http://192.168.1.9:8080", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    ...`
But offcourse it don't work, because there're a class cast exceptions
06-20 08:10:22.560: E/AndroidRuntime(2851): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient cannot be cast to com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient

Answer (score 0):

You have an `AsyncTask` within an `AsyncTask`.

```
client.get("http://192.168.1.9:8080/", new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
```

This is an `asyncCall`, it does not waits and program goes immedialtely to `onPostExecute()` just after this line.

**WRONG IMPLEMENTATION** of `AsyncTask`.

***Quick Solution*** can be just remove the AsyncTask and call this in `UIThread` and in `onSuccess` do the UI Updates using some handler.